# Make Insert statement in Javascript Using ADODB.Recordset

Tags: javascript, sql, insert, adodb

How to execute an `INSERT` statement using a javascript ADODB.Recordset object?

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
/* Getting access to the database */
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connectionstring = "Data Source=srvp7rnd-herm;Initial Catalog=hermes;User ID=hermes;Password=hermes;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
connection.Open(connectionstring);

/* JavaScript obect to access a SQL query's results */
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

/* Getting the current MAX(id) from the database */
rs.Open("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Screen_Template", connection);
rs.MoveFirst;
var maxID = rs.Fields.Item(0);
maxID = maxID + 1;

/* TODO: Get the last UID */
var sql = "INSERT INTO Screen_Template(template_name, OpCo, env, template_xml, language, id, title, role, UID) VALUES (" + templateName + "," + opco + "," + env + "," + "<hello>hello</hello>" + ",eng," + maxID + ",Hermes SMS message composer," + "manag, 10)";
alert(sql);
rs.Open(sql, connection);

/* Closing the connections */
rs.close;
connection.close;
```

But when I'm trying to run that code it gives me an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this code. If Screen_Template column type is Varchar, you have to append "'" to your variables. If SQL statement from alert(sql) was correct format with your Table Schema, it should be okay. Hope this help.

```
   /* Getting access to the database */
    var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var connectionstring = "Data Source=srvp7rnd-herm;Initial Catalog=hermes;User ID=hermes;Password=hermes;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
    connection.Open(connectionstring);

    /* JavaScript obect to access a SQL query's results */
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

    /* Getting the current MAX(id) from the database */
    rs.Open("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Screen_Template", connection);
    rs.MoveFirst;
    var maxID = rs.Fields.Item(0);
    maxID = maxID + 1;
    rs.close;

    /* TODO: Get the last UID */
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Screen_Template(template_name, OpCo, env, template_xml, language, id, title, role, UID) VALUES ('" + templateName + "','" + opco + "','" + env + "'," +"'<hello>hello</hello>'" + ",'eng'," + maxID + ",'Hermes SMS message composer'," + "'manag', 10)";
    alert(sql);
    rs.Open(sql, connection);

    /* Closing the connections */
    //rs.close;
    connection.close;
```